# Jquery Select Features auto age on Birthday instead of Input Type Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I make auto compute age when the user select month, day and year. I have a code for  wherein it auto compute the age. But I want to have  instead of input. Please help me to fix this :(

Here's my input type="date"

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" disabled id="age" name="age">
```

Here's my Jquery

```
 $("#dateofbirth").change(function(){
            var today = new Date();
            var dob = new Date($("#dateofbirth").val());
            var age = new Date(today - dob).getFullYear() -1970;
            $("#age").val(age);

});
```

Here's the [JSFIDDLE Working For Input Type="date"](http://jsfiddle.net/deanilvincent/n3yskb4w/)

Please help me to convert it to select like this below

```
<select class="form-control" id="dob-month">
    <option value="0">Month</option>
    <option value="January">January</option>
    ...
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="dob-day">
    <option value="0">Day</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    ...
</select>

<select name="b2byear" class="form-control col-sm-3" id="dob-year">
    <option value="0">Year</option>
    <option value="2004">2004</option>
    <option value="2003">2003</option>
    ...
</select>
```

And it will auto compute in here:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" disabled id="age" name="age">
```

Comment: Though you have comparatively small task, and you might not be interested in using external library. I am commenting for those who have similar kind of things to do, but they have to use multiple times at multiple places. Try this library : http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go with **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/n3yskb4w/1/)**. I've added a `class` for your each `select`. See inline comments for more detailed explaination!

```
$('.year,.month,.day').on('change',function(){ //call change function on all 3 select dropdowns
    var selectedYear=$('.year').find('option:selected').val();//get selected year
    var selectedDay=$('.day').find('option:selected').val();//get selected day
    var selectedMonth=$('.month').find('option:selected').val(); //get selected month
    if(selectedYear!=0 && selectedMonth!=0 && selectedDay!=0) //check if all the 3 dropdown values are selected
    {
        var today = new Date();
        var dob=new Date(selectedDay+"/"+selectedMonth+"/"+selectedYear); //convert to a valid date
        var age = new Date(today - dob).getFullYear() -1970; //calculate age
        $("#age").val(age);//display it
    }
})
```

---

**UPDATE**

Few Changes with **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/n3yskb4w/4/)**:

```
$('.year,.month,.day').on('change',function(){
    var selectedYear=$('.year').find('option:selected').val();
    var selectedDay=$('.day').find('option:selected').val();
    var selectedMonth=$('.month').find('option:selected').val();
    if(selectedYear!=0 && selectedMonth!=0 && selectedDay!=0)
    {
        var today = new Date();
        var dob=new Date(selectedDay+"/"+selectedMonth+"/"+selectedYear);
        var age = today.getFullYear() - dob.getFullYear();//just get it directly here
        $("#age").val(age);
    }
})
```

---

**UPDATE 2** with **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/n3yskb4w/6/)**

```
$('.year,.month,.day').on('change',function(){

    var selectedYear=$('.year').find('option:selected').val();
    var selectedDay=$('.day').find('option:selected').val();
    var selectedMonth=$('.month').find('option:selected').val();
    if(selectedYear!=0 && selectedMonth!=0 && selectedDay!=0)
    {
        var today = new Date();
        var dob=new Date(selectedYear,(selectedMonth-1),selectedDay); //convert to date in this format
        var age = today.getFullYear() - dob.getFullYear();//just get it directly here
        $("#age").val(age);
    }

})
```

---

**UPDATE 3** with **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/n3yskb4w/10/)**

> The HTML standard for forms appears to be such that disabled input
>   elements do not contribute to the form name/value collection.

So you won't get to capture the value of disabled field and I would suggest, instead of making input field `disabled` make it `readonly` and add a class to it to make it feel `disabled` with some styles added to it as below:

**CSS**

```
.readoly{
    color:darkgray;
    background-color: rgb(235, 235, 228);
    border:1px solid !important;
}
```

Comment: God bless and thanks a lot sir. I'll add the year up to 1920 :D

Comment: Great!! Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: @truelogicINC.. Updated answer with new calculation in code!! check it!!

Comment: Sir I'm having a problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/deanilvincent/n3yskb4w/5/ Here Sir When I chose 13, 17 etc. Its says nAN :(

Comment: what you choose as 13, 17?? date, month or year?

Comment: Try sir put 13 in the day. :(

Comment: Sir. Thank you so much sir. I've tried the second answer below and it works softly. Thanks a lot sir for your time and effort :D

Comment: @truelogicINC.. Added an update!! Check and let me know!! and please don't address me with **Sir**.. :) You can call me Guru!!

Comment: Guru! I having a problem now :(

Comment: I'm now on sending the value on the database. But it sends only "0" instead of the age. I found out I don't have any value="" inside the input but I don't know how can I put the id into the value to send the age in the database. Here guru <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" disabled id="age" name="borrowersage"> :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. It's currently 26th May, so inputting a DoB of 1st December 1977 should result in age 39, but it doesn't - it shows age 40. Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Try this     [DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v4vishnuprasad/n3yskb4w/2/)

```
 $('#dob-day,#dob-year,#dob-month').on('change',function(){

    var today = new Date();
    var dob=new Date($('#dob-month').val()+"/"+$('#dob-day').val()+"/"+                $('#dob-year').val());
    console.log(dob);
    var age = new Date(today - dob).getFullYear() -1970;
    $("#age").val(age);


        });
```